# How to check if table have action handler

Tags: spring-mvc, vaadin

in my vaadin/spring application i have a table which can have added action handler. Is there any option how to chcek if table already have an action handler ?

Answer (score 1):

I checked source code of `com.vaadin.ui.Table` class and how it deals with Action handlers - and unfortunately, I didn't find any direct way how to check how many action handlers there are in the Table (Vaadin version 7.7.6) - thats because the only exposed methods which deal with action handles are these:

- `addActionHandler` - for adding action handlers
- `removeActionHandler` - for removing specific action handler
- `removeAllActionHandlers` - for removing all action handlers

However, good news is that the addActionHandler method will add the new handler only if it wasn't already added. So if you just want to be sure that you haven't added your handler twice, just impelment the `equals()` method in your handler and it shouldn't be added twice. See code of method `com.vaadin.ui.Table#addActionHandler` and maybe set some debug points there...